# Buffer.from() creating memory leak How to resolve this issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I am upload large video file to server then s3 bucket. But now I am getting memory out issue due to Buffer.From used. How can I save it from memory leak? Memory not clear after stream finished.

Note:

I want to maintain stream pipe so that I can modify stream before uploading to s3.

```js
const passToS3 = new PassThrough();
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: config.access_key,
  secretAccessKey: config.secret_key,
});

const fileReadStream = new Readable({
  read(size) {
    if (!size) this.push(null);
    else this.push();
  },
});

const fileUploadPromise = [];


const busboyUpload = (req) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const busboy = Busboy({ headers: req.headers })
    busboy.on("file", async (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimeType) => {
        console.log(filename)
      
        fileUploadPromise.push(
            new Promise((res, rej) => {
              s3.upload(
                {
                  Bucket: // bucket-name,
                  Key: //filename,
                  Body: passToS3,
                  contentDisposition: "attachment",
                },
                (err, data) => {
                  if (err) {
                    rej();
                  } else {
                    
                    console.log(data, "===>")
                    res({ ...data, originalname: filename, mimeType  });
                  }
                }
              );
            })
          );
        fileReadStream.pipe(passToS3);
        file.on("data", async (nextChunk) => {
        fileReadStream.push(Buffer.from(nextChunk)); // memory--leak xxxxxxxxxxxx
      });
      file.on("end", () => {
        fileReadStream.push(null);
      });
    });
    busboy.on("finish", () => {
      Promise.all(fileUploadPromise)
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data[0])
          resolve(data[0]);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);
  });

app.post("/file-upload", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("dfjalkdf")
    const uploadedFileData = await busboyUpload(req);
    req.file = uploadedFileData;
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error==>",err)
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("server is running");
});
```

```
fileReadStream.push(Buffer.from(nextChunk));
```

this is creating a memory allocation and now After finish memory still have the memory maps.

Comment: What is the extra `fileReadStream` in the middle for? Can the busboy `file` be passed do s3 instead?

Comment: fileReadStream.push(Buffer.from(nextChunk));??

Comment: Yes that one,  why did you need a custom stream handler instead of piping the existing `file` stream.